# Why is $g$ tied to the oscillator strength $f$ in $\log{gf}_{\odot}$

Tags: spectroscopy, stellar-astrophysics

The $\log{gf}$ value of an element in a star, where $f$ is the [oscillator strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillator_strength), or probability of transition in an atom, is [a scientifically pursued quantity](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0712.1185v1.pdf) with relation to the model atmosphere of the star. Why is the oscillator strength tied to $g$? And what is the motivation for including this quantity in a stellar model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't make it clear, but you *may* be confused about what $g$ is. It is the statistical weight of an atomic energy level.

The $gf$ value, which refers to a particular transition between two energy levels in an atom/ion, is used because there is symmetry in terms of emission/absorption processes once the statistical weight is taken into account.
$$g_1 f_{12} = - g_2 f_{21}$$

If you just quoted $f$, then you would also need to know what the appropriate statistical weight was in order to calculate transition probabilities.

Comment: Ah, ok, yes I was confused. In the context of a stellar photosphere, would the statistical weight of an energy level be governed by the Boltzmann factor $\exp(-E/kT)$? So, if you know log(gf), and you know f (from physics), then could you determine an estimate of $T_{\mathrm{eff}}$?

Comment: @user44816 The statistical weight is the number of degenerate quantum states in an energy level.